# combining sublists created from regex expressions

Tags: python, list

I used a regex expression which extracted numbers from some line and this created  some list which i combined using the append function how do i combine these  sublists into one list

```
fname=input('Enter file name:')
if len(fname)<1:
  fname='regex_sum_42.txt'
fhand=open(fname)
total=0
numlist=list()
for line in fhand:
  line.rstrip()
  numl= re.findall('([0-9]+)',line )
  if len(numl)<1:
    continue
  numlist.append(numl[0:])
print(numlist)
```

What i got : [[1,2,3],[4,5]] ,i expected to get [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: I take a shot: Try `numlist.extend(num1[0:])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working too hard: why process the file line by line when you can process the whole file at once?

```py
# Assume file_name is defined

with open(file_name) as stream:
    contents = stream.read()
    
numbers_list = re.findall(r"\d+", contents)
numbers_list = [int(number) for number in numbers_list]
print(numbers_list)
```

#### Notes

- I used the regular expression `r"\d+"`, which is an alternative form. `\d` will match a digit.
- By default, `re.findall()` will return text, which we need to convert to integers if needed

Answer (score 2):

One solution to flatten your list of lists.

```py
sum(numlist, [])
```